# Does exist an expression lightning component and/or expression lightning web component equivalent to SLDS expression?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components, slds

In the [SLDS documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/), I've found a whole [page](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/expression/) about expressions, how to use them and how to make them similar to the ones implemented in Salesforce UI.

[image: example image]

Does exist something similar as a lightning component and/or as a lightning web component or should I have to implement it by myself? I've searched the [component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library) without success.

Answer (score 0):

LWC's as of now do not support conditional expressions when rendering any content. So you wont be able to use conditions like

```
<template  if:true={AND(OR(a,b),c)}></template>
```

Instead you can get the values from js file

```
get isTestCondnMet(){
     return ((a || b) && c);
}
```

and use this in html to render your contents

```
<template  if:true={isTestCondnMet}>
    Your content goes here
</template>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply but I don't understand how this could help me. I was looking for a component already implemented by Salesforce. Since there is a whole chapter about expressions I thought that it was somewhat a standard that one could use in lightning web/aura component.

Comment: In the last days I worked on build this functionality from scratch. When it will be completed I will post here as future reference even if I'm still hoping for a solution that doesn't involve building it from scratch for easier maintenance in future Salesforce releases.